# Calculating partial derivative

Tags: integration, derivatives

How can I calculate the following derivative?
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\int_{0}^{x_1}f(x_2,y)dy}{\partial x_2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Leibniz Rule, $$\ \ \ \frac{\partial \int_{0}^{x_{1}}f(x_{2},y)dy}{\partial x_{2}}=\int_{0}^{x_{1}}{ \frac{\partial f(x_{2},y)}{\partial x_{2}} dy}$$.

Comment: this doesn't render properly..

Comment: @Jebruho, please do check your LaTeX before you post something...